# Regex for urls and markdown like images

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble making two regex for a url parser in JavaScript. Let me explain.

I have two different regex, one to parse images with a markdown syntax, and one to parse plain urls.

So, if I have `![Alt Text](https://stackoverflow.com/)` it should parse to `<img src="https://stackoverflow.com/" alt="Alt Text" />`

And if I have `https://stackoverflow.com/` it should parse to

The thing is, this doesn't work, when I parse the image, later the src inside img parses to `src="<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"></a>"`

These are my regex:

```
parsedString = parsedString.replace(/\!\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\)/gim, '<img src="$2" alt="$1" target="_blank" />')
parsedString = parsedString.replace(/\b(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)\b/gim, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>')
```

My links work fine but I can't see the images that way. I thought maybe detecting if a url starts with `"` to not parsing it to an anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **image** replace try:
Regex: `/\!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/gim`
Replace with: `<img src="$2" alt="$1" />`

For the **link** try:
Regex: `/(?<!src=")(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)\b/gim`
Replace with: `<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>`

---

This regex uses the negative look behind to ensure that the link does not have `src="` preceeding it. Parse the text for the image markup then the link markup.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Also, you had a typo on the image regex, it should be `/\!\[(.*?)\]\((.*)\)/gim`

Comment: No worries, I have edited the regex - it should be `/\!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/gim`, good catch. The / should be a ? to make it “lazy”. See https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy#lazy-mode

Answer (score 1):

For the alt part, you can also use 2 capture groups with negated character classes instead of lazy quantifiers.

Note that only have to use the `/g` flag to get all matches and you can omit the `/im` flags at the end as you are not matching case insensitive characters and the pattern does not use anchors.

```
\!\[([^\][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y15Cvw/1)

```js
let parsedString = "![Alt Text](https://stackoverflow.com/)"
parsedString = parsedString.replace(
  /\!\[([^\][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)/g,
  '<img src="$2" alt="$1" target="_blank" />'
)
console.log(parsedString);
```

For the url part, you can omit the capture group and use the full match $& in the replacement.

Note that this pattern uses a positive lookbehing, which has [this support](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind).

```
(?<!\S)https?:\/\/\S+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B2i084/1)

```js
let parsedString = `https://stackoverflow.com/

src="https://stackoverflow.com/"`;
parsedString = parsedString.replace(
  /(?<!\S)https?:\/\/\S+/g,
  '<a href="$&" target="_blank">$&</a>'
)
console.log(parsedString);
```

Without a lookbehind, using a capture group:

```js
let parsedString = `https://stackoverflow.com/

src="https://stackoverflow.com/"`;
parsedString = parsedString.replace(
  /(?:^|\s)(https?:\/\/\S+)/g,
  '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>'
)
console.log(parsedString);
```